# Cannot hit Dockerized .net core application using localhost and port

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have .net core 3.1 dockerized and up (`docker-compose up --build`) from docker container but I still cannot reach any swagger url from the application using `http://localhost:8080/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "MyApp.API": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5001;http://0.0.0.0:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /home/app 
Copy ... projedct files ommited on purpose for clarity ...
RUN dotnet restore 
COPY . . 
RUN dotnet publish MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj -o /publish/ 
WORKDIR /publish 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.API.dll"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.0' 
services:  
  api:
    ports: 
      - "8080:5000"
      - "8081:5001"       
    build:
      context: .      
      dockerfile: MyApp.API/Dockerfile
    image: myapp/api:runtime
```

Comment: you are not exposing the port 5000 and 5001

Comment: Try to [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) the ports from container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using port 5000 and 5001 instead of 80 and 443 for your http(s) requests? If you're using Visual Studio, it will generate a Dockerfile for you that exposes port 80 and 443 by default. If you really want to use 5000 and 5001, you can expose those in your Dockerfile.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
WORKDIR /home/app 
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 5001
Copy ... projedct files ommited on purpose for clarity ...
RUN dotnet restore 
COPY . . 
RUN dotnet publish MyApp.API/MyApp.API.csproj -o /publish/ 
WORKDIR /publish 
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.API.dll"]
```

Comment: or in your compose file